# How to insert data into Elasticsearch from a CSV file in Go?

Tags: go, elasticsearch

I want to build a feature in my Go microservice, where I can upload a CSV file and insert the data inside it into Elasticsearch. The columns can vary with every file. I am familiar with the file uploading part, but could not find any efficient method to insert the data. Is there any Go library to insert data into Elasticsearch from a CSV file?

Comment: https://github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch Official client. There's an example of adding data.

Comment: Please check below my answer and marked as solution and upvote if it really helps you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Elasticsearch official [Go client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/go-api/current/installation.html).

You can use bulk api to index multipul documents together. Please check Bulk example [here](https://github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/tree/main/_examples/bulk).